# Создание XML с помощью PHP

Tags: xml, кодировка, php

Доброго времени суток!
Делаю создание XML страницы. Данные беру из MySQL с помощью SELECT.
Таблица имеет кодировку utf8_general_ci
XML создаю с помощью обычного **echo**. 
Когда вывожу русский текст из таблицы:

```
<text>  $row[text] </text>
```

то получаю

```
��! ��� � ������ ����...
```

хоть сам php файл в кодировке UTF без BOM и заголовок XML текста:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

Прошу помочь. Что делать с такой кодировкой?
И нормально ли то что это файл .php . И то что в нем код извлечения из таблицы и прочие функции?
И прошу заметить, что это только внутри этого xml. До этого стоит echo с русским текстом. Он работает нормально.

*p.s. Английский выводится без проблем.*

Добавление для Shrek:
[image]

Comment: Значит все таки данные из БД не в UTF-8

Comment: Добавил скриншот в первый пост. Может есть способы проверить какая кодировка? Или преобразовать?

Comment: AddDefaultCharset UTF-8 уже есть в .htaccess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добился нужного результата при помощи добавлении следующего:

```
mysql_query("set names 'utf8'");
mysql_query ("set character_set_client='utf8'");
mysql_query ("set character_set_results='utf8'");
mysql_query ("set collation_connection='utf8_general_ci'");
```

С чем это может быть связано?

И еще вопрос:
Когда я создаю XML через echo, то на странице не вижу сами теги. Только то, что в них написано. Это правильно?

Comment: Естественно. Точно так же, если бы мы написали 

    echo '<p>Text</p>';

то увидели бы только слово **Text**, но без тегов.

Comment: Но потом парсер сможет спокойно распознать XML?

Comment: Слово **парсер**, уже используют как хотят, поэтому я даже не знаю, какой смысл вы вкладываете в это понятие. А вообще, XML - это по сути тот же язык разметки, что и HTML. Так почему же с ним должны возникнуть трудности?

Comment: Прошу прощения за мою неспособность правильно выражаться. 
Благодарен, что правильно поняли. 
Пойду прочту точное определение парсера. А за ответы - спасибо!

Comment: Почему я не могу принять свой ответ? как быть?)

Comment: @Эмиль Сабитов, а вот с последним вопросом, я вам точно не помогу ))

Comment: Может создайте ответ с текстом из вашего комментария. Я его приму. Не хочется терять проценты принятых ответов.

Comment: @Эмиль Сабитов, для принятия своего ответа нужно подождать 2 дня.
Сейчас Ваш ответ принят.